# Am I understanding correctly the flow for function-to-function authentication using Managed identities?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-managed-identity

I'm building 2 Azure Function Apps that will communicate with each other using HTTPS. I've read [some articles](https://endjin.com/blog/2019/06/secure-function-to-function-authentication-in-azure-without-the-need-for-credentials) and so far it should be configured as the following:

1. Function App A should have a System Assigned Identity in order to authenticate itself.
2. Function App B should be created with a built-in authentication via AAD (in other words EasyAuth), and an existing, or new, application will need to be configured with the AD
3. Function App A's managed identity needs to be used to be registered as a user for the AAD Application
4. Use the [Azure Identity](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/main/sdk/identity/Azure.Identity) package in order to fetch the token from the AD, and then pass it into the Authorization headers as a Bearer token.

The article was written in 2019 and unfortunately I haven't found any newer information, but is the process still the same?

TIA!

Comment: that seems correct, if you can grant permissions to identity of App A

Comment: What kinds of permissions exactly?

Comment: add that identity as a user of an application as far as I understand